# Spring boot JPA One to One Mapping

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have two entities as below:

***User Entity***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private UserDetails userDetails;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public User(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

***UserDetails Entity***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_details")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userDetails")
    private User user;

    public UserDetails(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

My flyway script as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`description` varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE `user_details` (
`id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int,
`description` varchar(255)
);

ALTER TABLE `user_details` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`);
```

When I start the app, the tables create fine. I want the user table to be the parent and user_details table to be the child which gets created perfectly fine. But when I insert a User in the database, the user_id column in the user_details table gets stored as null. Below is my controller.

***UserController***

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity < User > getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

        User user = userRepository.getOne(id);
        return new ResponseEntity < > (user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity < User > saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {

        User userSaved = userRepository.save(user);
        return new ResponseEntity < > (userSaved, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

***UserRepository***

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

Why does the user_id column in the user_details table gets stored as null?

Below is my curl:

```
curl - X POST\
http: //localhost:5000/users \
    -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'\ -
    H 'Content-Type: application/json'\ -
    H 'Postman-Token: 22a98f2b-d3cc-4127-b3ad-35f28c916fa4'\ -
    d '{
"description": "Some user",
"userDetails": {
    "description": "Some user details"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is not appropriate. The owner of the relationship is `UserDetails`. So relationships should be present in `UserDetails` Entity.

Find the mapping added below.

**User Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserDetails userDetails;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public User(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**UserDetails Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_details")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public UserDetails(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, the above approach should be correct and there is more easier way to do that instead of using association, you can using advance hibernate `@Embedded & @Embedable feature` if you want I can show you a quick example as well.

Comment: @Amit Mishra, but with `@Embedded & @Embedable feature` it will not consider Embedded class as a separate entity. Here we have two tables present it the DB

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I just wanted to share that this also can be a very good way

Comment: @SSK why do you say that the owner is user_details. I want two tables where user is the parent and user_details is the child such that there is a column in user_details called user_id that is foreign key mapped to id of the user table. So, doesnt that make 'user' as the owner?

Comment: @SSK I tried your changes. Two things went wrong : 1) the tables that are created, I don't see a foreign key constraint in the user_details table(i have removed flyway and using jpa auto create ) . I need the foreign key contraint in the user_details 2) When I hit my curl that i given above, the voucher_id column in user_details is again null.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, where you want to keep some details common between the Entities. For example, you've a table `DepartmentUser` and other `User_address` and you've one more table `ManagementUser` and in this table also you want to map user address because both type of users will have address and you may want to use association in this case! But Hinbernate does have an awesome feature called `Embedding entity`. You can simply embed the user address in each entity where you need to put this in.

This can be done this way.

```
@Entity
class DepartmentUser{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValues(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private String eamil;
   @Embedded
   private UserAddress address;

//Standard setters and getters
}
```

Another table User address

```
@Embaddable
class UserAddress{
  private String state;
  private int zip;
  private String country;

//Standard setters and Getters
}
```

This will simply append your Department User DB with the columns in UserAddress and this also result in good performence.